# How can i short a "foreach" so it display only 3 things?

Tags: php, foreach, short

Im trying to display only 3 videos(the 2nd, 3rd and 4th) from my database but I really cant make it work. 
I try adding this `if ($i++%2==1) {` to the code but i doest work

```
<?php foreach ($articles as $article) { 

$category = $article['article_category'];
if ($category == "video")
  {
  ?>
<iframe width="325" height="186" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $article['article_video']; ?>?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>        
<?php  
  }
  }
?>
```

Could i get some help thanks

Comment: the smarter thing to do is to only select the 2nd, 3rd and 4th in the first place

Comment: Why not just do a for loop from 2-4, and then inside just set `$article = $articles[x]`?

Comment: thanks dagon, the things is im bad at php dont really know how to.

Comment: then why not ask that question instead

Comment: Yeah, can't you put a `LIMIT 3` on your `SELECT`

Comment: Don't use the "fix" tag unless you mean the FIX protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Slice the array with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice), then loop as normal:

```
foreach( array_slice( $articles, 1, 3) as $article) {
```